# injection of $scope and $http throws an error

Tags: angularjs

I just wrote :

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('SearchController', [ '$scope, $http', function( $scope, $http ) {
}]);
```

...and i get the following error :

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.3/$injector/unpr?p0=%24scope%2C%20%24httpProvider%20%3C-%20%24scope%2C%20%24http Q/<@http://welcomepage.local/vendor/angularjs-1.3.min.js:6:414
```

I just followed examples on official documentation, can you tell where i'm wrong ?
I'm using v 1.3.0-rc.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
app.controller('SearchController', [ '$scope', '$http', function( $scope, $http ) { // you missed '' here 
 }]);
```

// you have to inject the dependencies `[ '$scope', '$http', functi..` note that `$http` and `$scope` is   inside `"` or `'`

Comment: Please don't use double quotes :o

Answer (score 1):

of course I have html :

```
<html ng-app="app">
    <body>
        <div ng-controller="SearchController">[...]
```